# Two tables in mysql, how to fetch data from those tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables..

**Client Bills** - Contains bill infor for clients

**from billRecievedFromClient** - contains the amount we receievd from client for a bill

**mysql> select * from clientBills;**

+------------+------------+------------+------------+

| date       | clientCode | billNumber | billAmount |

+------------+------------+------------+------------+

| 2012-02-17 | C0001      | B0001      |    1200.00 |

| 2012-02-17 | C0001      | B0002      |    1000.00 |

| 2012-02-17 | C0002      | B0003      |    1233.00 |

| 2012-02-18 | C0003      | B0004      |   12000.00 |

| 2012-02-18 | C0001      | B0005      |     400.00 |

+------------+------------+------------+------------+

**mysql> select * from billRecievedFromClient;**

+------------+--------------+---------------+--------+---------+

| Date       | receivedCode | forBillNumber | amount | remarks |

+------------+--------------+---------------+--------+---------+

| 2012-02-18 | R0001        | B0001         | 200.00 | CASH    |

| 2012-02-18 | R0002        | B0001         | 300.00 | CASH    |

| 2012-02-18 | R0003        | B0002         | 300.00 | CASH    |

| 2012-02-18 | R0004        | B0003         | 233.00 | CASH    |

| 2012-02-18 | R0005        | B0001         | 700.00 | CASH    |

+------------+--------------+---------------+--------+---------+

**Now i want Information Like this ---** i.e. for client C0001 , there are 3 bills. And he made payment for one bill completelly, for one bill partially and one bill complete amount is due..

+------------+------------+------------------------------------+

| billNumber | billAmount | SUM(billRecievedFromClient.amount) |

+------------+------------+------------------------------------+

| B0001      |    1200.00 |                            1200.00 |

| B0002      |    1000.00 |                             300.00 |

| B0005      |    400.00 |                             00.00 |

+------------+------------+------------------------------------+

remember since he not started payment for third bill, there wont be any entry for that in second table..

What can be the query for this??

please suggest..

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: someone format question please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`

`SELECT *, SUM(t2.amount) FROM clientBills t1 LEFT JOIN billRecievedFromClient t2 ON t1.billNumber = t2.forBillNumber`

Anyway There won't be record for non started bills.
But if u want NULL record for non started bills u can add at the end of query : `GROUP BY t1.billNumber`

Comment: It is fetching only one row.. and sum is of all the rows......                +------------+------------+----------------+
| billNumber | billAmount | SUM(t2.amount) |
+------------+------------+----------------+
| B0001      |    1200.00 |        1733.00 |
+------------+------------+----------------+

Comment: Ah, I see, Try adding at the end of query `GROUP BY t1.clientCode,t1.billNumber` If it wont work paste somewhere SQL with schema and some data to play with ;)

Comment: Exact query is --SELECT t1.billNumber,   t1.billAmount, t1.clientCode,  SUM(t2.amount) FROM clientBills t1 LEFT JOIN billRecievedFromClient t2 ON t1.billNumber = t2.forBillNumber  group by billNumber having t1.clientCode= 'C0001';